# Send email with double angle brackets (open-close) in content by Python Gmail-API

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I want to send an email by the Gmail-API in Python, but I constantly received the following error:
`<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Invalid value for .....">`

I tried to change everything and concluded that the error happens when I include **an double open close angle bracket ('<<' and '>>') (see example)** in the email.  I tried everything to parse the text to something else, but i'm thinking that the problem lies in the fact that i use 'raw'... But 'raw' is the only way the example of Google shows.

Is there an other way to send an email by the gmail-api? or, in other words, what can I do to be able to send an email with angle brackets in the text?
Thanks!

My current code is below (example code from Google):

```
import base64
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes
import os

from apiclient import errors

(...other code...)
SendMessage(service, "me", CreateMessage("me", sender, "<<NOT OK>> " + action, "TEST!"))
(...other code...)

def SendMessage(service, user_id, message):
    """Send an email message.

    Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

    Returns:
    Sent Message.
    """
    try:
        # print message
        message = service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()
        print '<mail> Message SEND (Id: %s' % message['id'] + ')'
        return message
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred (SendMessage): %s' % error


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    """Create a message for an email.

    Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

    Returns:
    An object containing a base64 encoded email object.
    """

    print "<mail> send to: " + to
    print "<mail> subject: " + subject
    print "<mail> message: " + message_text

    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the angled brackets?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! No, I didn't try that, which escape code do you have to use to escape the angled brackets?

Comment: The backslash `\\`, put that before your angled bracket :)

Comment: The backslash did not work, if i send \<, the receiver gets the same \<.  But I noticed something different.  Actually, the exameple I showed (with <NOT OK>) works (I will change my original post), but it's when I use a double angle bracket <<NOT OK>>, the example fails...  Is the angle bracket an escape character for something else?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure :(
Try checking the escape chars in the Python docs

Comment: "<NOT OK>>", "<<NOT OK>" and "<<NOT OK>>" fail, the combinations with one bracket succeed.

Comment: Gmail loves HTML, maybe you could try to replace `<` and `>` by their HTML entities, `&lt;` and `&gt;` resp.

Comment: I guess I have to tell gmail then that the message is in HTML?  Because the receiver gets the same HTML entities (in plain text)

Comment: If I were you I'd use something like [Beautiful Soup](www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it can turn HTML into plain text, it's great :)

Comment: Or if Gmail accepts the good old SMTP protocol, its use is well documented in the Python Standard Library Reference Manual ...

Comment: Thanks for the options, but I like to use the Gmail-API because the rest of my application is written with the API.  And it looks like overkill to use HTML, when I just want to send some characters...
There must be an other solution ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())

with the *url-safe* base64 alphabet, otherwise you'll have invalid characters in your 'raw' field.  See:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Comment: Sometimes, I feel google just loves to take a dump on developers. Using this api has been one roller coaster ride.